# AFNetworking Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 “Request timeout"

Tags: ios, objective-c, timeout, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

When I launch my app after some times the first request with cellular data not working, I have Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 (request Time out). All works fine in Wifi. When i retry with cellular data all works. Only the first request is not working.

Thanks to help.

Comment: increase requestTimeOut Time in AFNetworking.

Comment: this is not a problem, i already wait more than 60 seconds for the timeout.

Comment: Which version of AFNetworking do you use?

Comment: i use 2.5.0, automatically updated with pod.

Comment: Have you got some updates on this issue?

Comment: No, I had to manually handle the exception and relaunch the request manually. Have you a solution ? Or the same problem ? ^^